# Swift/iOS8: allow only certain keyboards

Tags: ios, swift, emoji, alamofire

How can I deny certain keyboards to be displayed in iOS8?

The actual case is that Users can make a REST Call in my Search Field - should they switch to the Emoji keyboard and send them, Alamofire will crash, not recognizing the Input --> subsequently my App crashes.

Comment: Filter bad input before sending it to the server.

Comment: Filter bad input at the server as well.  Otherwise someone could hack your server by sending a bad REST call with cURL or wget.

Comment: Why do some people down vote this? The question is fine. Explain what's wrong instead of down voting please! Stack overflow is a place to learn :)

Answer (score 2):

Rule 1 in security:

### **Never Trust User Input**

Filter the input. You can not trust the user's input even after denying some keyboards.

You may want to use a **regex** for the filtering.

Side note: You will have to do the filtering on the server side too. Your API may be called from an other location. Potentially, that's a huge security issue. Hackers can do some nasty things if you don't filter your parameters.